# Yii 1 - Where do I put the form processor file when using a php form

Tags: php, forms, yii

I am in the process of replacing out a Yii form in Yii 1 frameowrk with just a regular php form.

The problem I am having is that, I can't figure out where Yii is looking for the form processor file when put it in the form action.

Right now I have the php file to process the form in the same folder as where the view is being stored. Where should I put the form processor php file so that Yii knows where to look for it?

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <p><b>Your Name*</b> <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br />
    <b>Subject*</b> <input type="text" name="subject" /><br />
    <b>E-mail*</b> <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <b>Body*</b><textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Yii routing system, because by default there is only one entry point for the yii application - index.php and you can't invoke your file direcly.

```
<form action="some/doSomething" method="post" >
    <p><b>Your Name*</b> <input type="text" name="yourname" /><br />
    <b>Subject*</b> <input type="text" name="subject" /><br />
    <b>E-mail*</b> <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <b>Body*</b><textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>

</form>
```

And then in your controller:

```
class SomeController extends CController
{
    public function actionDoSomething()
    {
        \Yii::import('path.to.your.contact.php');
        $yourname = \Yii::app()->request->getPost('yourname');
        $subject = \Yii::app()->request->getPost('subject');
        $email = \Yii::app()->request->getPost('email');
        $message = \Yii::app()->request->getPost('message');
        // run you methods from contact.php
    }
}
```